# Lucky bottle cap #32 series 1

Tags: rebus

[image]

use the symbols on the bottle cap to complete this word or phrase.

picture is from www.riddles.com

Comment: why would some one downvote this, it was a nice rebus puzzle..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is the idiom:

> "Take it or leave it"

Specifically,

> T + (-C)AKE + IT + OAR + LEAF + IT

Comment: correct good job!